# Difference between shuffle() and rebalance() in Apache Flink

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink, partitioning, flink-streaming

I am working on my bachelor's final project, which is about the comparison between Apache Spark Streaming and Apache Flink (only streaming) and I have just arrived to "Physical partitioning" in Flink's documentation. The matter is that in this documentation it doesn't explain well how this two transformations work. Directly from the documentation:

> **`shuffle()`:** Partitions elements randomly according to a uniform distribution.
>
> **`rebalance()`:** Partitions elements round-robin, creating equal load per partition. Useful for performance optimisation in the presence of data skew.

Source: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html#physical-partitioning

Both are automatically done, so **what I understand** is that they both redistribute equally (`shuffle()` > uniform distribution & `rebalance()` > round-robin) and randomly the data. Then I deduce that `rebalance()` distributes the data in a better way ("equal load per partitions") so the tasks have to process the same amount of data, but `shuffle()` may create bigger and smaller partitions. **Then, in which cases might you prefer to use `shuffle()` than `rebalance()`?**

The only thing that comes to my mind is that probably `rebalance()`requires some processing time so in some cases it might use more time to do the rebalancing than the time it will improve in the future transformations.

I have been looking for this and nobody has talked about this, only in a mailing list of Flink, but they don't explain how `shuffle()` works.

**Thanks to [Sneftel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787480/sneftel) who has helped me to improve my question asking me things to let me rethink about what I wanted to ask; and to [Till](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815083/till-rohrmann) who answered quite well my question. :D**

Comment: what made you think that `rebalance`was random?

Comment: It is not random, it tries to put the elements in a balanced way for the processing to be more efficient, but if this is the only difference, then i find no reason for "shuffle()" to exist as "rebalance()" does the same in a more efficient way.

Comment: what makes you think that `rebalance()` is more efficient? They're just different approaches. `shuffle()` is a randomized approach to load-balancing, `rebalance()` is an explicit greedy one.

Comment: From the documentation I understand that `shuffle()` distributes the elements in a random and uniform way so it may not create same loaded partitions, meanwhile `rebalance()` tries to create all the partitions with the same load. Then I deduce that `rebalance()` does the same but in a more efficient way for the work distribution as all the TaskManagers will have approximately the same data to process. Then if `rebalance()` does better the same job, why will anyone use `shuffle()`? May the processing needed by `rebalance()` produce more latency than which it can improve in some cases? Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the documentation states, `shuffle` will randomly distribute the data whereas `rebalance` will distribute the data in a round robin fashion. The latter is more efficient since you don't have to compute a random number. Moreover, depending on the randomness, you might end up with some kind of not so uniform distribution.

On the other hand, `rebalance` will always start sending the first element to the first channel. Thus, if you have only few elements (fewer elements than subtasks), then only some of the subtasks will receive elements, because you always start to send the first element to the first subtask. In the streaming case this should eventually not matter because you usually have an unbounded input stream.

The actual reason why both methods exist is a historically reason. `shuffle` was introduced first. In order to make the batch an streaming API more similar, `rebalance` was then introduced.

Comment: `rebalance` today uses random channel to start: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/3466c228926f03bc44236d4634a6656f63dd2011/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/partitioner/RebalancePartitioner.java#L42

Answer (score 2):

This statement by Flink is misleading:

> Useful for performance optimisation in the presence of data skew.

Since it's used to describe `rebalance`, but not `shuffle`, it suggests it's the distinguishing factor. My understanding of it was that if some items are slow to process and some fast, the partitioner will use the next free channel to send the item to. But this is not the case, compare the code for [`rebalance`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/3466c228926f03bc44236d4634a6656f63dd2011/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/partitioner/RebalancePartitioner.java#L46-L49) and [`shuffle`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/3466c228926f03bc44236d4634a6656f63dd2011/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/partitioner/ShufflePartitioner.java#L40-L42). The `rebalance` just adds to next channel regardless how busy it is.

```java
// rebalance
nextChannelToSendTo = (nextChannelToSendTo + 1) % numberOfChannels;

// shuffle
nextChannelToSendTo = random.nextInt(numberOfChannels);
```

The statement can be also understood differently: the "load" doesn't mean actual processing time, just the number of items. If your original partitioning has skew (vastly different number of items in partitions), the operation will assign items to partitions uniformly. However in this case it applies to both operations.

**My conclusion:** `shuffle` and `rebalance` do the same thing, but `rebalance` does it slightly more efficiently. But the difference is so small that it's unlikely that you'll notice it, `java.util.Random` can generate 70m random numbers in a single thread on my machine.